# Does a certain type of connected subset exist in Euclidean spaces having an arbitrarily high dimension

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb R$ be the set of all real numbers and for each positive integer $n$, let $f_n$ be a mapping of $\mathbb R^n$ into $\mathbb R$. For each positive integer $n$, does there exist an $f_n$ whose graph is (1) connected (2) dense in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ and (3) contains no subset which is a bounded (non-degenerate) connected subset of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$? Such an $f_n$ exists when $n=1$. But I do not know what the situation is even when $n=2$.

Comment: What is your example for $n=1$?

Comment: I can prove the answer is yes, but it involves a big piece of machinery and so is not very constructive.

Comment: @Forever Mozart: Thanks a lot for the "yes" answer which is all that I hoped for.

Comment: @Grumpy Parsnip: Among the solutions of Cauchy"s  well known functional equation f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) for all x,y in R, are some that satisfy all three of the above conditions. These functions are everywhere discontinuous and even non-measurable. The proof of their existence probably requires the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: @GarabedGulbenkian Please also see my answer to your question here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36017/a-question-about-the-dispersion-points-of-connected-metric-spaces/237759#237759.